# VTK rotation in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, vtk

I am developing projects in WPF and C#. I am trying to make a 3D object rotate around x, y and z axis respectively.

It looks to me something like this should work:

```
#include <vtkConeSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkTransformPolyDataFilter.h>
#include <vtkTransform.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkXMLPolyDataWriter.h>

int main(int, char *[])
{
  //Create a cone
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkConeSource> coneSource = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkConeSource>::New();

  {
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter> writer = 
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter>::New();
  writer->SetInputConnection(coneSource->GetOutputPort());
  writer->SetFileName("original.vtp");
  writer->Write();
  }

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
  //transform->RotateWXYZ(double angle, double x, double y, double z);
  transform->RotateWXYZ(10, 0, 1, 0);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter> transformFilter = 
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter>::New();

  transformFilter->SetTransform(transform);
  transformFilter->SetInputConnection(coneSource->GetOutputPort());
  transformFilter->Update();

  {
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter> writer = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter>::New();
    writer->SetInputConnection(transformFilter->GetOutputPort());
    writer->SetFileName("transformed.vtp");
    writer->Write();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

although it is in C++.

However, it seems there is no in vtkSmartPointer C#, so how can I use vtkTransform in C# to make an object rotate? Or it should be some other ways?

Thanks  a lot. This is first day I am using VTK, so please by any chance explain a little slowly :)

Comment: @Clemens It is a existing project that already used VTK. I suppose VTK can be more flexible and scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use vtk smartpointers with C# because C# takes care of the memory management itself.

For the transform line you could use:

```
vtkTransform transform = vtkTransform.New()
```

There are numerous C# examples for VTK at: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/CSharp if you want to see the formatting.

Comment: The vtkTransform.RotateX() is what I am using, but it did not give me what I wanted. It is sort of rotation that I don't know how to describe, but absolutely not the rotation along some axis. I will post more code in the original thread.

Comment: RotateX(angle) will rotate around the X axis as you would expect.  I'd suggest you display the code in a window a slow rotation to see what is occurring.